# Free space from .git folder after `git add hugefile.bin`

Tags: bash, shell, git

Take a look at this:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test/
test$ git init
Leeres Git-Repository in test/.git/ initialisiert
test$ head -c 1G </dev/urandom >hugefile.bin
test$ du -sh .
1,1G    .
test$ git add hugefile.bin 
test$ du -sh .
2,1G    .
test$ git reset hugefile.bin
test$ du -sh .
2,1G    .
test$ git gc --prune=now
Nothing new to pack.
test$ du -sh .
2,1G    .
```

So what can I do to remove the obviously still present garbage information about `hugefile.bin`  from my `.git` directory?

Comment: Answered on [so]. See [How can I delete a file from git repo?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2047465)

Comment: Nope. Just nope. I am **not** trying to do `git rm` or `git reset` and I have **not** committed anything that I want to take back. This is about only `git add` taking space which can not be freed again.

Comment: {shrug}. If you don't like that solution I can't help you any more.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `git gc --prune=now` removes the Git object for me on Git 2.20.1.

Comment: @DavidPostill Dude, I don't and didn't want to sound rude but "that solution" you linked just has absolutely nothing to do with my problem. If you tried to reproduce my problem (the code I provided has no dependency other than git) you would notice that.

Comment: @DanielB That is very interesting! I'm still on 2.19.1 so that might be a clue.

Comment: git rm --cached hugefile.bin ?

Comment: @Rusi `fatal: pathspec 'hugefile.bin' did not match any files`